# An Algebraic Version of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following set of real numbers $\mathcal{X}=\{1,2,3,\sqrt{2}+1,\pi+\sqrt{2}\}$. Lets consider the set of all linear combinations with integer coefficients of these numbers which I will define as $span(\mathcal{X})=\{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2\sqrt{2}+\alpha_3\pi:\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

It seems this is analogous to linear algebra with respect to integer coefficients. A basis for $span(\mathcal{X})$ is $\{1,\sqrt{2},\pi\}$.

Is there a name for this? Where should I look for this and what terms should I search for? I am an engineer and am very familiar with linear algebra but not with algebra. What is the correct terminology for saying $\mathcal{X}$ has dimension 3 over the integer coefficients?

Thanks,

Comment: "Vector spaces" with rings instead of fields as scalars are called modules.

Comment: And your example is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, a.k.a. an abelian group. In fact, it's finitely generated, which is the closest thing to finite-dimensional in the module world.

Comment: Ok so what I call span$\mathcal{X}$ is actually the "module" generated by $\mathcal{X}$ over the "ring" of integers?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have here an example of a *free module* over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. The adjective *free* means that the module is isomorphic to the Cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ via the map 
$$
\alpha_1+\alpha_2\sqrt{2}+\alpha_3\pi\mapsto (\alpha_1, \alpha_2\, \alpha_3).
$$
One also says, in analogy with vector space notation, that $1, \sqrt{2}, \pi$ is a *basis*. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is commutative, any other basis of the module must consist of exactly three elements.

(Note that, unlike vector spaces, not all modules are free. As an extreme example consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module. There are also examples of modules over non-commutative rings which are free but admit bases of different cardinality.)